# What is the right and secure way to set session in java

Tags: session, cookies

I understand that we can use
Cookie
URL Re-Writing
Hidden Form Fields
HTTPSession Object

What is the most secure way to set sessions in Java?

Cookies: Clients have control to manipulate the cookie value, Moreover, these are also prune to Session Hijacking or User Impersonation attacks, Another drawback would be the size limitation.

Hidden Form Fields: Can be easily seen in the source.

URL Rewriting: Has its own limitation, Like, If a user leaves our site by following any link to 3rd party and then coming back to the site, how to ensure the URL contains the session information (Ofcourse encrypted). Eg. when going to a payment gateway and then coming back to the site.

HTTPSession Object: I would assume this is secure as its on the server side. But, How does it work internally and how does it identifies the user?

I can always employ security certificates and use SSL for secure communication, but what is the standard practice?

Answer (score 0):

Standard practise is to use a cookie if you are making use of a server side session.

If you are using SSL your exposure to session hijacking will be minimal. The client *can* manipulate the cookie value, but the chances of a client guessing another user's cookie ID are very, very small. Also if you require clients to authenticate to the site you will usually also have an authentication cookie that is tied to the session cookie, so changing either would invalidate the other.

Not sure what you mean by the size limitation?